# Can complications with modules used in scripts occur when switching from Python 3.4 to Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-3.7

Currently I have some scripts with Python 3.4 running on my windows server and few running under Python 2.7.

Now I want to switch from Python 3.4 to 3.7, but do not install Python 3.7 in parallel.

Can this lead to errors in my scripts or is 3.7 to 3.4 easily downward compatible?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Migrating from 3.4 to 3.7 should be fairly non-disruptive, but you'll have to test your code to see. Anything that fails should crash and so you'll be able to investigate (e.g. `RuntimeError` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)

Comment: The [What's new in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/index.html) series goes over all of the changes between Python versions.  There are changes that *could* break your code moving form 3.4 to 3.7, but most of them are quick fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably going to be downvoted to the ground because this is information you can probably find easily. Usually this is information you can get in the release notes: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/

But normally all versions of Python 3 are backwards compatible with previous versions of Python 3.